# TypeScript: Infer type of abstract method's implementation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to have a base class with a property whose type is inferred from a method's return value, which method is implemented by descendent classes.

So, the base class could be smg like this:

```
abstract class MyBase<T> {
    protected myProperty: T;

    constructor() {
        this.myProperty = this.getValueForMyProperty();
    }

    protected abstract getValueForMyProperty(): T;
}
```

And a descendant:

```
class MyDescendant extends MyBase<MyDescendant1PropertyType> { // MyDescendant1PropertyType should be like ReturnType<(MyDescendant.getValueForMyProperty)>
    protected getValueForMyProperty(): MyDescendant1PropertyType {
        return {
            prop1: "smg"
        };
    }
}
type MyDescendant1PropertyType = {
    prop1
}
```

Now this works, but it has a lot of boilterplate noise for the typing.
I would like to describe the rule:

**The type of `MyBase.myProperty` is of type `MyDescendant.getValueForMyProperty`.**

I don't need the type information in `MyBase`, only in `MyDescendant`.

So what I want is smg like this:
(This code does not complie)

```
abstract class MyBase<T /*infer from below, don't want to type it in descendants*/> {
    protected myProperty: ReturnType<getValueForMyProperty>; // Don't know the right syntax for this

    constructor() {
        this.myProperty = this.getValueForMyProperty();
    }

    protected abstract getValueForMyProperty(): T;
}

class MyDescendant extends MyBase {     // Don't want to add the generic part, MyBase<anything>
    protected getValueForMyProperty() { // Don't want to manually add return type
        return {                        // Return type should be inferred
            prop1: "smg"
        };
    }
}
```

Can I do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that is *almost* what you want.  The limitation is that in order for it to work, `getValueForMyProperty` must be `public`.

The crux of this setup is that instead of using the generic `T` to describe the return type, we use `T` to describe the object itself.  That way, we can create specific instances like this:

```
class MyDescendant extends MyBase<MyDescendant> {
    public getValueForMyProperty() {
        return {
            prop1: "smg"
        };
    }
}
```

In order to do that, we say that the generic `T` on `MyBase` must extend this interface:

```
interface CanGetProperty {
    getValueForMyProperty(): unknown;
}
```

Typescript interfaces only describe the `public` properties of an object and cannot use modifiers like `protected` or `private`.  That is why this setup requires that the `getValueForMyProperty` method on `MyDescendent` must be public.  Otherwise it would not fulfill the required interface.

Somehow I didn't get an error when implementing the `protected abstract` method with a `public` one?  That seems like it should be an error so I'm removing the `protected` from `MyBase` as well.

The types for `MyBase` are now a bit messy, but that's ok because this is just one place.

```
abstract class MyBase<T extends CanGetProperty> {
    protected myProperty: ReturnType<T['getValueForMyProperty']>;

    constructor() {
        this.myProperty = this.getValueForMyProperty();
    }

    abstract getValueForMyProperty(): ReturnType<T['getValueForMyProperty']>;
}
```

I tested it out in [this Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/qNB0dW) and I'm getting good inference of the return type on descendants with different types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect for me :)